# Prove that if a complex-valued function is real differentiable, then limit of line integral around circle exists

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been working on the problem below and really haven't gotten anywhere. For part (1) I've tried the function $f(z) = \bar{z}^2 / z$ but couldn't get it to work and for part (2) I've not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Let $C(z,r)$ denote the circle centered at $z$ with radius $r$. Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on a domain $D$. For each $z \in D$ let
$$ A(z) = \lim\limits_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{2\pi i r^2} \int_{C(z,r)} f(\zeta) d\zeta $$
if the limit exists.

(1) Give an example of a continuous function $f$ defined on a domain $D$ such that $A(z)$ does not exist for some $z \in D$.

(2) Show that if $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable on $D$, then $A(z)$ exists for $z\in D$. Find the limit.

Comment: the square on the r is part of the problem

Comment: @DanielFischer: No it is probably right as it stands. Note the $d\zeta$ in the integral; it is not arc length. You get zero for a constant $f$; the example $f(z)=\bar z$ is instructive. And my guess is that the answer is $\partial f/\partial\bar z$ …

Comment: D'oh, yes, with only $r$, the limit would exist for all continuous $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us put $z=0$ for simplicity. Surely, we can translate our results to work for other $z$.

Write $$f(\zeta)=f(0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\zeta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}\bar\zeta+o(|\zeta|^2),$$
with the partial derivatives evaluated at $0$. Integrate around a circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin and let $r\to0$. Note that $\zeta=re^{it}$ gives $d\zeta=ire^{it}$, and you quickly find that the integral evaluates to
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}+o(1).$$
This answers (2), and probably gives a hint for the search for a solution to (1):
I would try
$$f(z)=\frac{\bar z}{\sqrt{|z|}},$$
for example.

I should have added this explanation of the partials:
$$ df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy
 =\frac12\Bigl(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}d(z+\bar z)-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}d(z-\bar z)\Bigr).$$
Collect terms and insist on having $$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}d\bar z,$$ and conclude
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac12\Bigl(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigr),\quad 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=\frac12\Bigl(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Bigr).$$

Comment: A more elementary solution might be to use Green's theorem to rewrite the path integral into an integral over the enclosed disk. But I think the above is possibly more instructive.